# Create new user with email as a soft deleted user

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, unique, soft-delete

I am using ActsAsParanoid for soft deleting users.After deleting(soft) a user, my client wants to create user with same email id.But it generating unique field error since email column is unique.So my question is can we set the uniqueness for `email` column only if the deleted_at column is null.

Pls reply if u dont understand my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could change the uniqueness constraint of your `users` table to be:

```
UNIQUE (email, deletion_date)
```

This would effectively:

- For standard (non-deleted) users, guarantee they have unique email addresses, since their deletion dates would presumably all be `NULL`.
- For deleted users, not make any guarantee about email addresses, since they all have unique deletion dates.
- For new users, allow them to use an email address that a deleted user has, since the new user will have a `NULL` deletion date, while the deleted user has a value there.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work on MySQL since NULL != NULL in a Uniqueness constraint check

Answer (score 0):

Ah, just change old email to something like

### Me@yourmail.com_deleted

That way if you need to view the old email it's everything before the underscore deleted.

In other words here have new user create new account.

Probably have a mutator in the background add the underscore deleted on the old account.

Underscore deleted just an example.